# How do developers of Raspbian test it on the Pi?

Tags: raspbian

How do developers of Raspbian test it on the Pi?

If an install takes say 30 minutes, then that's 30 minutes for every combination of installation configuration and model of Pi and its components - let alone hardware that might be used with it.

Would this be run on a farm of Pi's? (Or should that be a bakery...)

Or the majority of the code split into modules that can be tested without going through the whole installation process?

And I assume much of it is done on virtual machines that are close enough to being equivalent to the Pi?

The reason I ask, is I use a minimal version of the Raspbian distro (FooDeas/raspberrypi-ua-netinst) and AFAIK it is slow to test; not ideal for development. I want to extend it, and maybe contribute to it, so wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Such a farm would explain why the *Zeros* are that rare in the wild.

Comment: [This article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/03/how-two-volunteers-built-the-raspberry-pis-operating-system/) on arstechnica has some info on the early development stages of raspbian. Sounds like there was at least some amount of automated testing for armv6/armv7 compatibility failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the Raspbian people do any tests at all apart from see if the packages compile reasonably cleanly.

There are said to be about 18000 packages.  I can't see that the (is it 2) Raspbian developers will have much time to test.

If you really want an answer ask the Raspbian developers.

Comment: Really?? 8-| Automated testing is supposed to be a time saver, so I'd really find that surprising but I don't know much about OS development let alone Raspbian. I didn't know there were just 2 of them either! I wonder how I can contact them... will have a search around - Thanks

Comment: @Jodes http://raspbian.org/